# Exact Target - Triggered send and Upsert and email case change

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have a form where Exact Target is setting up a triggered send so that once it is submitted, a party involved (an email account submitted) is sent an email. I'd noticed when that trigger was added that the page was doubling the new records in the system and determined through exclusion that the triggered send function is also updating the data extension. I can see a line which must be (for lack of other references) the detail which loads the subscriber email address. I noticed that many of those addresses are sent in all upper case as they are coming from an older database. In order to unify the tables appearance (and to master the function) I'd like to convert the case of the email to all lower case every time.

```
SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", RequestParameter("email"))
```

I'm wondering if the AMPscript function

> %%=Lowercase(@name)=%%

can be added in here to force the case change but I don't want to risk breaking the script.

Comment: Are you thinking that the casing of the email is allowing the records to be duplicated - or has that issue been resolved, and you are now just wanting to ensure lowercase insertions?

Comment: Johnny - would you mind splitting this into two questions, so we can answer each individually - thanks!

Comment: Kelly J. - It's actually just the one question wondering how to ensure the data going into the extension is all lower case. The double post was a concern before but when I removed my upsert entirely, the code inserted for the triggered send apparently performs the data insert also. That code was supplied by someone else here and I'm not sure how it does what it does, but it works so I'm fine with that.

Comment: Got it - wasn't sure what the actual question was from the title.  Answer posted.

Comment: Is this question answered for you, or no?

Comment: If this worked, would you mind marking it as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to ensure lowercase email address going into the data, try the following code -

```
SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", Lowercase(RequestParameter("email")))
```

Comment: ^ Exactly what the job required.